# Certificates across servers and WCF

Tags: wcf, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate, wif

I have a website, wcf service, and a security token service (STS) running on one server.  Everything works great.  I am now trying to now seperate the peices across servers.  When the website trys to login to get the token I get ssl cert errors.

This would be on Server 2008 and IIS 7.5 and my windows 7 IIS 7.5 while i debug.

```
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://x.x.x.x/STS/issue/wstrust/mixed/username. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by...
```

I generated a self signed cert on the STS server and exported it to the website server.  I also exported the key and gave IIS access to the key on the website server.  That got past a bunch of WIF errors, it would not run, but I'm not sure that its the right thing to do.

I also have tried [netsh http add sslcert ipport:0.0.0.0:44400 ect...]  but im not sure what port to use, ive tried a half dozen different ones and none seem to work, and 443 wont work.

The website is using a WSTrustChannelFactory to create the connection.  It bombs on the channel.issue command at the bottom.

```
 var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                 new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                 new EndpointAddress(signInEndpoint));
             factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

             factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
             factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

             var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

             var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
             { 
                 RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                 AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(realm),
                 KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer
             };


             try
             {
                 var genericToken = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
```

** EDIT **

I've also set website servers iis default website https bindings port 443 to use the cert that i imported from the STS server and get the same error.

** End Edit  **

I've been all over google and stackoverflow and while many questions seem to be close, none of the approved answers have worked.

Ideas?  I'm a server/hardware noob so the "for dummies version" would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it the reason it doesnt work is that my laptop is not on the same domain as the iis server???

Comment: I am having the same problem trying to use the API call to IdentityServer.  Did you ever solve this issue?  We have this problem when the IdentityServer is running on the same machine as the Client, with the self signed cert in Trusted CA root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since u are using a self signed certificate, have u made sure to turn off [Certificate Chain Validation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-identity-foundation-wif-how-to-change-certificate-chain-validation-settings-for-web-applications.aspx) or else add it to the trusted store. It looks like u are using the url of IdentityServer, in there u can turn off strong endpoint requirements and on the client use a UserNameWSTrustBinding with only message security.

Comment: I didn't try the suggestion but I understand the need of chain validation and was the right direction.